# File upload using Swift Vapor 3.0

Tags: swift, alamofire, vapor

I'm trying to create a simple vapor service so I can upload video files (one at a time) through an api.

From my app I'm uploading the video file using Alamofire:

```
func uploadVideo(video: URL) {
    Alamofire.upload(videoFileURL, to: "http://localhost:8080/upload").responseString { response in
      debugPrint(response)
    }
}
```

The vapor controller method is like this (this is where I don't know how to do it):

```
func upload(_ req: Request) throws -> String {

  let data = try req.content.decode(Data.self).map(to: Data.self) { video in
    try Data(video).write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/eivindml/Desktop/video.mp4"))
    return Data(video)
  }

  return "Video uploaded";
}
```

How do I get the video file from the request and into the right format so I can write it do disk?

The method `upload()` is called correctly etc, as it works if I just have the last return statement.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your function it appears you're not handling your future response correctly, or extracting the data.

```
func upload(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<String> {
    return try req.content.decode(File.self).map(to: String.self) { (file) in
        try file.data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/eivindml/Desktop/\(file.filename)"))
        return "File uploaded"
    }
}
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Hmm, now I get `[ ERROR ] VaporError.httpDecoder: There is no configured HTTPMessageDecoder for content type: application/octet-stream.`

Comment: If the content type is `application/octet-stream` then you don't need to use `ContentContainer` (`req.content`). That is for _decoding_ content from the request body, but in this case the body is just a stream of bytes. Use [`req.http.body.consumeData(...)`](https://api.vapor.codes/http/latest/HTTP/Structs/HTTPBody.html#/s:4HTTP8HTTPBodyV11consumeDataXeXeF) instead.